# The object is not null when it is in debug mode, but is null when it is called by a method?

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception

when I run my TreeNode code, the compiler say the TreeNode that be called by countUnivalSubtrees method is null. But, when I run debug mode, it tells me that the Treenode I create is not null. The object, foolbar, of class Treenode has its root, left branch and right branch. So why when the foolbar is called, the method is received a null object?

[image]

[image]

1.The Treenode code

```
package lc_250;


public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode root;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode() {}
    TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    public void put(int val){
        this.root =  put(this.root, val);
    }
    private TreeNode put(TreeNode node_now, int val){
        if (node_now == null) return new TreeNode(val);
        else if (val < node_now.val) node_now.left = put(node_now.left, val);
        else if (val > node_now.val) node_now.right = put(node_now.right, val);
        else node_now.val = val;
        return node_now;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeNode foolbar = new TreeNode(3);
        foolbar.put(5);
        foolbar.put(6);
        foolbar.put(3);
        foolbar.put(2);
        foolbar.put(4);
        foolbar.put(9);
        foolbar.put(8);
        foolbar.put(7);
        cson250 foolclass = new cson250();
        int num = foolclass.countUnivalSubtrees(foolbar);
    }
}
```

2. The cson250 code

```
package lc_250;
public class cson250 {
    public  int num = 0;
    public  int countUnivalSubtrees(TreeNode root) {
        count(root);
        return num;
    }

    public boolean count(TreeNode root){
        if (root == null) System.out.println("bro Treenode is null");
        boolean left = count(root.left);
        boolean right = count(root.right);

       if ( root.left == null && root.right == null){
           num++;
           return true;
       }

       if (left&&right){
           if (root.left!=null && root.left.val != root.val){
               return false;
           }
           if (root.right!= null && root.right.val != root.val){
               return false;
           }
           num++;
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: After `if (root == null) System.out.println("bro Treenode is null");` I think it would be a good idea to return no?

Comment: I understand the NPE, but could you please better describe what you mean with the "debug" situation? Which code do you debug, at which point do you show the variables watch?

Comment: When I run my code, this line worked, and print "bro Treenode is null". So when the foolbar is called, it should be null. But when I use debug mode to check where goes wrong, debug mode showed foolbar contains values. I just really confused.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm debugging the Treenode code. And I set breakpoint at ```foolbar.put(6);``` , and ```foolbar.put(4);``` These two lines

Comment: The variable watch I set is just object foolbar. It can be seen it has root with value.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, it should be ```  if (root == null) return true; ```, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing a different point in the debugger then where the NPE is happening. This is the reason why your watched fields don't show that `root == null`.

In every leaf of your tree, the `root` will be `null`, so when you encounter the first leaf (should be the node with val "2", since this is the smallest value in your list and you put the smaller values on the left nodes and you check the left nodes first in your `count` method), you will first execute

```
if (root == null) System.out.println("bro Treenode is null");
```

but then your code continues execution of

```
boolean left = count(root.left);
```

and there the `NullPointerException` occurs, because `root` of course still is `null` and so you cannot access `root.left`.

All your checks to prevent the recursive call happen after the call, so they don't really help to stop accessing a `root` that is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, if you want to see your tree node as null in debug mode, make your code look like this, so as to put debug point when root == null.

```
public boolean count(TreeNode root){
    if (root == null) 
        System.out.println("bro Treenode is null");
```

This way you will see your root in null at some point in your program flow.
You can put a debug point at line where you are printing System.out.println("bro Treenode is null");

Comment: Cool trick, thank you and I'll try this to see how thing is going.